# how to display first array in first row then second array in second row then third array in third row

Tags: php

how to display first array in first row then second array in second row then third array in third row

```
    Array
    (
    [S] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 61
                    [area_code] => SS-5
                )

        )
    [A] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 24
                    [area_code] => AHUP-9
                )
        )

    )
```

[image]

Comment: Its very urgent anyone help me

Comment: Show your desired output

Comment: Please include - example input, desired output, and eventually what have you tried. "first array in first row" - do you mean table row or what it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: What do you want to get as output?

Comment: sir i want ''S" display in first row then "A" array display in second row

Comment: Sir its very urgent

Comment: You need to be correct. Show your desired output. It should be one string for each `A` or `S`? Like `id = 22, area_code = AHUP-7`?

Comment: sir i will give you output demo

Comment: sir my output format display in above

Comment: @Developer, for this output you've missed input data column.

Comment: #3 in https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic Doesn't show any effort to solve. Homework type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use simple `foreach` loop with concatenation:

```
foreach($data as $upkey=>$set){      
    foreach($set as $ind=>$value){  

        echo $value['area_code'];  

        if (isset($set[$ind+1])) echo '-----';
    }   
    echo PHP_EOL;  
}
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/VEIYa)**

If you need a table with columns and rows you can use simple example like:

```
// open table(thead included) and tbody tags
echo '<table class="table"><thead></thead><tbody>';       

foreach($data as $set){    
    // open row
    echo '<tr>';                            
    foreach($set as $value){   

        // print column with value
        echo '<td>'.$value['area_code'].'</td>'; 
    }   

    // close row
    echo '</tr>';                           
}

// close tbody and table tags
echo '</tbody></table>';
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/4LGf0)**